# Como bajar un texto en un div usando bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

como puedo bajar el texto change para que aparezca en el medio del contenido usando bootstrap

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <div class=" row justify-content-center mt-5">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="/Order Sumary/images/icon-music.svg" alt="">
        <span class="h6"> Annual Plan</span>
        <span class="text"><a href="">Change</a></span>
        <p>$59.99/year</p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

No se como puedo hacer para bajar un poco más el enlace (texto) Change he probado con todo con margin por ejemplo y nada

Comment: No es claro el resultado esperado, pareciera que con un `<br>` entre los `<span>` es suficiente.

Comment: hice un update a mi respuesta, creo que es el resultado que esperas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puse un borde para verlo mejor, lo único que tiene que hacer es cambiar la clase del margin (mt-5) de lugar

UPDATE:
Hice algunas modifcaciones per mantuve el grid como lo tenias.

- Primero puse un col-12 para que abarque toda la pantalla
- Después quite el `justify-content-center` de donde lo tenias y creé un nuevo div de tipo flex para poner el contenido y listo

```css
.box {
  border: solid 1px red
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row box">
  <div class="col-12 my-5">
    <div class="justify-content-center d-flex">
      <div class='text-center'>
        <img src="/Order Sumary/images/icon-music.svg" alt="">
        <span class="h6"> Annual Plan</span>
        <span class="text d-block"><a href="">Change</a></span>
        <p>$59.99/year</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```